# Storing user and pass in SQL Server to be used by Python application

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, security, encryption

**Reason for my question:**
I build Python based interfaces that connect to an SQL Server to query multiple linked servers. This has been easy for me to use as we simply use ADOM groups and grant access to specific linked servers so a user can use our Functional accounts to access data from many different linked servers. We have run into an issue where the database admins want us to move away from using linked servers and instead get our own functional account to then store said accounts on the SQL Server and simple retrieve those login details for use directly against other databases instead of using the linked servers.

**My question:**
How can we store login details on our SQL Server securely and then retrieve them using Python to then be used as credentials directly against other database servers through a Python ODBC library.

For example I can use something like the below code to pull login details for the functional account I need to use to connect to another database but I am not sure if this would be secure or if I need to somehow encrypt the login details on the server side and decrypt them in the Python program or not.

Can someone provide some insight on what the correct practice would be for something like this?
We have a lot of federal regulations to follow concerning security so a secure method of getting the login details and using them is the goal.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import pyodbc


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.un = ''
        self.pw = ''
        if 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' not in pyodbc.drivers():
            box.showerror('Error Manager', 'You are missing the required driver for this tool.\n'
                                           'Please install the ODBC driver "SQL Server Native Client 11.0".')

        else:
            try:
                conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', host='host_name',
                                      database='database_name', trusted_connection='yes')
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                with conn:

                    q_string = "SELECT user, pass from database.dbo.table_name"
                    cursor.execute(q_string)
                    result = cursor.fetchall()
                    self.un = result[0]
                    self.pw = result[1]
                    self.connect_to_database()

            except BaseException as e:
                print('Exception: {}'.format(e))

    def connect_to_database(self):
        try:
            # Using the pulled Username and Password to connect to separate database.
            # What do I need to do at this point so the User and Pass remain secure?
            conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', host='host_name',
                                  database='target_database_name', user=self.un, password=self.pw)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            with conn:

                q_string = "SELECT * from database.dbo.table_name"
                cursor.execute(q_string)
                result = cursor.fetchall()

        except BaseException as e:
            print('Exception: {}'.format(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you explored the doing column level SQL Server encryption using symmetric keys.

Comment: @AtmanirbharBharat I do not know what all that would require also that portion would be on the server team. I need to mostly know what is needed on the python side.